How can I see only people of a certain album in digikam?
I've migrated away from Lightroom to digikam as my photo library management (the LR subscription model is too expensive). The migration went fairly well as all the metadata was written inside the JPEG's, digikam had no trouble reading that.
In LR I could find people of a certain collection by selecting that collection and pressing O which brought up the faces view for photos in that collection only.
I want to do something similar in digikam, but can't understand how I can filter the People view to only show photos of a specific album, which are defined in my library by simple folders.
The reason is that I sometimes forget someone's name, but I know they have tagged photos in a certain album. In Lightroom I would open that album (collection), show the faces and quickly find the persons name. I am trying to do the same in digikam.
I've tried the following so far without any success:

looked on the web,
checked the manual
checked Photo.SE
View -> Separate Items -> By Faces

This separates photos by the amount of tagged faces in the photo


Use the table view of an album and sort by tags

This does not give a distinct list of (People) tags used in the album




I might have misunderstood, but it sounds like you're looking for the Advanced Search function.
A new advanced search can be created in a defined album and with specific tags using the drop down menus and putting a tick in the box next to the tag(s) you want.


Thanks, but I'm not looking to find specific people, I want to get an overview of all people tagged in a selected album. So if I have an album of a trip with James, Mehmet and Abby this view would only show their thumbnails in the people view. I use this when I e.g. forget the name of Mehmet, but remember he joined the trip. I would open the album navigate to this desired view and see his name next to his photo.
Sorry for not explaining my question well.

If you select the "Views" tab and "Icons" in "Configure digiKam" (under "Settings") and tick the box to "Show digiKam tags", do the tags appear with the thumbnail in the Album view? (They do on mine (Ubuntu), but I'm a bit of a tag minimalist - I don't know what happens if there are a lot of tags associated with a particular image.)
